# Empty check is not working in JSP

Tags: jsp, for-loop, is-empty

I have my `forEach` in my code.

I try to check is the teams are empty, if that is true, result should be other than false.

```
<tbody>
<c:forEach items="${teams}" var="team">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${not empty teams}">
            var1 is NOT empty or null.
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            var is empty!
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

The problem is with otherwise or if... empty teams.

It is'not working.

That string is not showing on a website.

Comment: Did you mean `${not empty team}` (without the "s" at the end ?

Comment: hmm, should I use var or items to check? I'm using teams now because I find that example in Internet, I dont remember where.

Comment: @J. Carrer specify clearly what you want to check or what you want to achieve.

Comment: If teams is empty the for loop is not executed. if teams is not empty the loop is executed but the `var is empty!`is never reached. therefor  `var is empty!` is never echoed.

Comment: Ok, I check it before foreach and if it is not empty, program starting foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `fn` function,

```
<tbody>
<c:forEach items="${teams}" var="team">

  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${fn:length(teams) > 0}">
        var1 is NOT empty or null.
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        var is empty!
    </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

You have to include `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>` for this.